# How do I reorder() by (variable1 - variable2) in a ggplot2 boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Here's my data frame `data.melt`

```
Id,Group,variable,value
1,a,score1,56
1,a,score2,23
2,b,score1,15
2,b,score2,45
3,c,score1,62
3,c,score2,95
4,d,score1,75
4,d,score2,11
```

Here's my boxplot-generating script

```
ggplot(data.melt) + 
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(
      x=Group,
      y=value,
      fill=variable
    )
  )
```

I know I can put a `reorder()` function for `x=`, but I'm unsure how to order the chart how I want.

I want it ordered by the difference between `score1`'s median `value` and `score2`'s median `value`. Is this possible with `reorder()`?

Comment: Do you mean the difference between `value` and the equivalent `median` for the `variable`? the difference between `score1` and `score2` median is a single number, i.e., `25` I'm also uncertain why you are making box plots of single values...

Comment: @ShawnMehan My boxplot's X axis is `Group`. Y axis is `value`. Each `Group` has two boxes, one for `score1`, the other for `score2`. I know I can order the X axis by median `value` with `reorder(Group,value,FUN=median)`. I want to order it by the difference between the medians of `score` and `score2`.

Comment: Rather `ggplot(df) + 
    geom_point(
        aes(
            x=Group,
            y=value,
            color=variable
        )
    )`?

Comment: @ShawnMehan I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Seems like you might want to just calculate the difference in medians for each `Group` and add it to the dataset as a variable that you can use `reorder`.   Without data that's more representative of the problem it's hard to test (you only have on value per `variable` category per `Group` at the moment).